# How to load multiple Admob Ads at once and show it in a queue

Tags: java, android, admob

i have been working on it since many days i have a task i had to do it in a while but it is not working.Can anyone help me out for this problem?I have to show multiple admob ads in a queue here is the code below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-1715420772455294~2411911048");
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-1715420772455294/7926895940");
    prepareAd();
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Load the next interstitial.
             prepareAd();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Wait Ad is loading",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onAdLoaded(){
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Ad did not load",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });
  }

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Ad did not load",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
public void  prepareAd(){


    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

}
```

This code is fine but not helping me because this loads ad on closed but i want to load multiple ads at once and on every close show it in queue like First In First Out (FIFO)

Answer (score 2):

For loading multiple ads you need to use the following class : **AdLoader**

```
adLoader.loadAds(new AdRequest.Builder().build(), 3);
```

There is a limitation to maximum 5 ("*his method sends a request for multiple ads (up to 5):*")

More info on how to load multiple ads: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native#loading_ads

Comment: How can i add them to queue ?